# matlab changing position of an element of a vector

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. I have a vector `v = [3 5 7 9 11]`. I need to change order of some elements. For example:

```
v = [3 7 5 9 11] %// by moving "5" after "7" or
v = [3 5 9 7 11] %// by moving "9" before "7"
```

In Java, I can do it simply using

```
Collections.rotate(array.subList(new_index,old_index ),1);
```

Is there any one line code in MATLAB like Java to do this? Thank you for help.

Comment: you call that "simply"? :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I'm beginning to understand why they say Java is a verbose language :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
v(new_index) = v(old_index);
```

where `new_index` and `old_index` can be vectors. In your examples:

```
v([2 3]) = v([3 2]);
v([3 4]) = v([4 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
>> v = [3 5 7 9 11];
>> v([1 3 2 4 5])    % moving "5" after "7" 
>> v([1 2 4 3 5])    % moving "9" before "7"
```